How to make smooth movement for a tunnel traveling music game?
I'm creating a music game where the player travels inside a tunnel and can create twists and turns while listening to music. Here's a video showing what it currently looks like.
I'm looking for advice on how to make a really satisfying movement mechanic. Currently, the movement is just like this: if the player presses, for example, D, the tunnel is transformed to the right according to some constant speed.
I think the aim is that the player can move freely however they want, but I want to make it so that the movement feels great when hitting it on the beat.
I'm thinking of maybe Bezier curves.

It's difficult to understand what you want to achieve from such a vague description. "make the movement really satisfying" is a highly subjective goal; what you find satisfying might be different than what someone else finds satisfying. Your video shows movement through a tunnel, but it's not clear how this relates to music, what the gameplay mechanics are, or what about the current motion you're dissatisfied with. Please try to explain in more detail how your game works and what you're trying to achieve.

In a general sense, smoothing is often achieved with linear interpolation (e.g. Vector3.Lerp(), or with more complex non-linear equations, such as (in Unity) `Vector3.SmoothDamp(). Without knowing what you want to achieve and how your code currently works, I can't say whether or how these would be applicable to your case.
