Is it possible to design character movement system with Bezier Curves?
For context, I'm trying to create a really dynamic and fast character. That can suddenly move slow, fast, zap into places, dash, and hover in place.
Say that I want to make a character accelerate a certain way when pressing "W". Then, I could easily create an animation of the character moving by using bezier curves in Blender.
In the actual game, Is it possible to allow the player to move the character by any bezier curve?
I know that one other way is to just use physics for the character and tweak some values until you get the velocity and movement that you want, but I'm wondering if there's a more intuitive way to do it like bezier curves.

In the actual game, Is it possible to allow the player to move the character by any bezier curve? In the actual game the player moves in exactly the way you program him to move.

This question appears to be related to https://gamedev.stackexchange.com/questions/210861/how-to-make-smooth-movement-for-a-tunnel-traveling-music-game

As tkausl suggested, if you are programming the game, then you can program the character movement to use bezier curves. How to implement this, and how difficult it is to implement, will depend on the programming language, engine, and editing tools you are using.
That said, you may find that movement with bezier curves (or any other type of premade curve) is not as intuitive as you were expecting:

If your character collides with anything solid while moving along the curve, you'll need to stop moving along the curve and switch to manual or physics-driven movement.
If the curve has more than two control points, it can be tricky to move along the curve at a consistent speed if the control points aren't spaced evenly.
Depending on the physics engine you are using, the physics engine may not behave as desired if you are moving some objects by editing their position rather than by applying forces.

